# How do I to resolve the error "No action instance for path could be created"

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I'm trying to run a simple "HelloWorld" with struts 1x (The website is based in it), but I can not to run the example the site is returned the following error:

```
org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources -   Resource org/apache/struts/action/ActionResources_en.properties Not Found.
2015-01-12 09:35:56,420 [http-bio-80-exec-10] ERROR     org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor - No action instance for path /helloWorld could be created
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.muchoslibros.actions.HelloWorldAction
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationClass(RequestUtils.java:124)
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationInstance(RequestUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.applicationInstance(RequestUtils.java:147)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionCreate(RequestProcessor.java:281)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.googlecode.webutilities.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.googlecode.webutilities.filters.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at net.muchoslibros.filters.ValidarPaisFilter.doFilter(ValidarPaisFilter.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using the following settings:

In my Action called HelloWorldAction:

```
public class HelloWorldAction extends Action {

public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
{
    return (mapping.findForward("success"));
}}
```

In my struts-config.xml

```
<action path="/helloWorld" type="net.muchoslibros.actions.HelloWorldAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/helloWorld.jsp" />
</action>
```

And in my jsp view helloWorld.jsp:

```
<-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<-- language: lang-html -->

<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<<html:form="/helloWorld">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
saludos desde struts 1
</body>
</html:form>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

I don't know what is the problem with it? Thanks for you helps.

Comment: is your class HelloWorldAction in classpath or classes folder of war or webapp?

Comment: It seams that your struts libs are not deployed with your app. Because the error says that they are not in classpath;) What app server do you use, how do you package that app, war/ear?

Comment: Thanks, The web application is not using a war or another file to deploy, this is contained into a folder y from the tomcat server is configured  with the files context.xml, servlet.xml and web.xml to run the application

Comment: I'm using eclipse, How can I to check if the HelloWorldAction is existing in the classplath ??

Comment: I'm checking another action that is working actually and is not declared in the .classpath or any config xml file, this action is only declared in the struts-config.xml the the action mapping section.

Comment: The action file exists in the classes folder

Comment: `net.muchoslibros.actions.HelloWorldAction` isn't being deployed, apparently.

Comment: Dave Newton, How can I to validate this?

Comment: Hi everyone!, this problem has been resolved, the project has been cleaned and built and the problem is fixed.